# Django ORM - partial match of rows in different tables

Tags: python, django, postgresql, orm, model

I have two different Django models, "modelA" and "modelB", who only have two columns in common with each other: "EMAIL" and "NAME", with the rest of the columns in each model being different. I want to return a single object list from "modelA" that but does not contain duplicate "EMAIL" and "NAME" combos in "modelB"...

For example, if "modelA" has the following objects:

```
EMAIL             NAME       SOMEFIELD
bob@email.com     Bob        ....
bob@email.com     Robert     ....
```

and "modelB" has the objects:

```
EMAIL             NAME       ADIFFERENTFIELD
bob@email.com     Bob        ....
sammy@email.com   Sam        ....
bob@email.com     Bobby      ....
```

I would want the final "modelA" queryset to return only:

```
EMAIL             NAME       SOMEFIELD
bob@email.com     Robert     ....
```

What is the most efficient way to do this Django? The best solution I can think of right now is to get the "modelA" query set and iterate through each object to test if the same "EMAIL" and "NAME" combo exists in "modelB", then if it doesn't, add that object to a new list. This sounds terribly inefficient though. And even though I have very little experience with Django, I know there must be a better way :) If it's relevant, my database is using PostgreSQL. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in just two queries:

```
from django.db.models import Q

b_models = modelB.objects.values('email', 'name')
exclude = Q()
for model in b_models:
    exclude |= (Q(email=model['email']) & Q(name=model['name']))

a_models = modelA.objects.exclude(exclude)
```

The `Q` object allows combining of filters with simple binary operators (`&`, `|` and `~` for SQL's `AND`, `OR` and `NOT`). This will exclude any pair of email and name that already exists in modelB's table.

If you were to filter by a single property (say just email), you could do:

```
emails = modelB.objects.values_list('email', flat=True)
a_models = modelA.objects.exclude(email__in=emails)
```

That would execute just a single query.

Answer (score 0):

Most efficient will be raw query. You certainly try to use Q or aggregation, but django does not generate pure and quick sql.

Please read about natural joins. 
[SQL natural join POSTGRES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334212/sql-natural-join-postgres)